# function is not defined at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I am using a validator in a form it is working. It shows the message when it should, but after clicking on submit, even with everything valid, it shows this error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Validate is not defined
>       at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit

```
<form id="details" class="add-listing-form" method="post" action="{{url('listing/'.$result->send_id.'/'.$step)}}" onsubmit="return Validate();" accept-charset='UTF-8'></form>
```

```js
$('#details').validate({
  rules: {
    'amenities[]': {
      required: true,
    }
  },
  messages: {
    'amenities[]': {
      required: "{{ __('messages.jquery_validation.required') }}",
    }
  },
  groups: {
    amenities: "amenities[]"
  },
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.attr("name") == "amenities[]") {
      error.insertAfter("#at_least_one");
    } else {
      error.insertAfter(element);
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: Where is the `Validate()` function defined? It's not shown in your code.

Comment: This is a laravel page is defined after call all the other scripts.

Comment: Can you please add an example of it to the question.

Answer (score -1):

The answers is i don't need to do that onsubmit="return Validate();" remove from form submit!

Comment: In this case the problem was a typo, and the question would be best to be deleted

Comment: As per documentation, wiki page for the tag, and the 6000+ questions on SO tagged jQuery Validate, using an inline click handler is not a good option, nor would the validate function be called on submission.  In fact, using jQuery alone negates the need for any inline event handlers for anything.  Like Rory said, might be best to delete this whole thing.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes Roy I have vote to delete

Answer (score -2):

You should define

```
function Validate()
{
    ...
}
```

in your script before calling it from HTML